# Could not understand working of vector.resize() and vector.shrink_to_fit()

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I came across 2 codes depicting the use of `std::vector::resize()` and `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()` and could not understand which one demolishes the elements of the vector.

[Example 1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-shrink_to_fit-function-in-c-stl/)

[Example 2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-resize-c-stl/)

In example-1 vector has all the elements even after `resize(5)` is used while in example-2 `resize(4)` eliminates the 5th element of the vector. Have a look and tell if I'm getting something wrong.

Comment: Please include code as text in the question

Comment: The page appears to state the output of its code, are you saying that output is wrong?

Comment: @George it is, the code has undefined behavior.

Comment: don't use code from that site to learn C++, it usually promotes bad practices and this example is utterly wrong. That code is not a valid C++ program

Comment: it is understandable that you are confused by that extremely misleading wrong example. Problem is: Without code in your question it is unlikely that it will be answered

Comment: @idclev 463035818 Ah yes so it does.

Comment: `resize` will destruct excess elements and shrink the container to match (if it's smaller than the new size). `shrink_to_fit` is a request to reduce the capacity of its container to match `size`. It doesn't really make sense to use these functions together.

Comment: You'r better of reading a serious reference, like https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;` - Yeah, I would not learn C++ from that site.

Comment: @George `resize` doesn't do the "shrink" that `shrink_to_fit` does. In particular it does not invalidate any references, and only invalidates iterators pointing past the new `end`

Answer (score 2):

That first example is undefined behavior as the vector only has 5 elements after `resize(5)` is called and elements up to index 9 are accessed. However, its likely to work in a release build as the memory for the rest of the elements haven't been freed yet. A debug build will probably catch the error though.

shrink_to_fit() won't change the contents of the vector. However, it might move the elements to a smaller piece of memory and free the old memory causing the previous bug to show.

The second example uses the vector correctly.